# How to make symfony forms support datetime-local input type?

Tags: php, html, datetime, symfony, formbuilder

Most of the browsers are dropping support for `datetime` and also `datetime-local` as a valid input type. As of the time of writing this question, there are more support for support for [`datetime-local`](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-datetime-local-element.html) than [`datetime`](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-datetime-element.html)(which is almost non-existent).

If you building forms using Symfony's form builder, it supports `datetime` but not `datetime-local`. So how would you make symfony form builder accept `datetime-local` input type and keep the rest of the functionality of the input type same?

Answer (score 3):

One way this problem can be solved is, if we can change the text of input type to say `datetime-local` which can be done by overwriting the `DateTimeType` and using that.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class DateTimeType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['widget'] = $options['widget'];

        // Change the input to a HTML5 datetime input if
        //  * the widget is set to "single_text"
        //  * the format matches the one expected by HTML5
        //  * the html5 is set to true
        if ($options['html5'] && 'single_text' === $options['widget'] && self::HTML5_FORMAT === $options['format']) {
            $view->vars['type'] = 'datetime-local';
        }
    }

}
```